# Equivalent Solution $\theta = C_1 e^{mx} + C_2 e^{-mx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to figure out combine these coefficient and find this form:

$\theta = C_1'\sinh(mx) + C_2'\cosh(mx)$

Anyone has a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write out the definitions:

$\theta = C_1^\prime {e^{mx} + e^{-mx} \over 2} + C_2^\prime {e^{mx} - e^{-mx} \over 2} = C_1 e^{mx} + C_2 e^{-mx}$.

Just multiply out on the left and equate coefficients of $e^{mx}$ and of $e^{-mx}$.

Comment: I wanna to workout the first equation to find the second, dont assume that this is true actually.

Comment: forget. this is main hint. I understood. tks.